# Spark: Entire dataset concentrated in one executor

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

[image]

I am running a spark job with 3 files each of 100MB size, for some reason my spark UI shows all dataset concentrated into 2 executors.This is making the job run for 19 hrs and still running.
Below is my spark configuration . spark 2.3 is the version used.

```
spark2-submit --class org.mySparkDriver \
    --master yarn-cluster \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 8g \
    --num-executors 100 \
    --conf spark.default.parallelism=40 \
    --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6000mb \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=6000s \
    --conf spark.executor.cores=3 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=8G \
```

I tried repartitioning inside the code which works , as this makes the file go into 20 partitions (i used rdd.repartition(20)). But why should I repartition , i believe specifying  spark.default.parallelism=40 in the script should let spark divide the input file to 40 executors and process the file in 40 executors.

Can anyone help.

Thanks,
Neethu

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're running your jobs in YARN if yes, you can check following properties.

```
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
```

In YARN these properties would affect number of containers that can be instantiated in a NodeManager based on `spark.executor.cores, spark.executor.memory` property values (along with executor memory overhead)

For example, if a cluster with 10 nodes (RAM : 16 GB, cores : 6) and set with following yarn properties

```
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb=10GB 
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=10GB
yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores=4
yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=4
```

Then with spark properties `spark.executor.cores=2, spark.executor.memory=4GB` you can expect `2` Executors/Node so total you'll get 19 executors + 1 container for  Driver

If the spark properties are `spark.executor.cores=3, spark.executor.memory=8GB` then you will get 9 Executor (only 1 Executor/Node) + 1 container for Driver

you can refer to [link](https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) for more details

Hope this helps